# Can we validate octet-stream data using JOI?

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I want to validate the payload data from postman which is sending as a octet-stream. Is it possible to validate this data

we use

```
  options: {
            validate: {
                query: Joi.object({
                    marketCode: Joi.string().required()
```

like this any way to validate octet-stream data

Comment: How about [Joi.binary()](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.7.0#binary)?